# Is it possible to have a conditional statement distinguish which model a Python variable is coming from?

Tags: python, sql, django

In my Django view I have 3 models and I want to execute some code  based condition from where a variable is coming from.

I have tried...

```py
    if (type(variable)) is ModelA:
        do this...
```

If I do `print(type(variable))` I am expecting `'<class 'app.models.ModelA'>` on console
But the conditional never kicks in. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if (type(variable)) is ModelA`, you should use `if isinstance(variable, ModelA)`.

demo:

```
❯ cat models.py
class ModelA:
    pass
❯ cat main.py
import models
variable = models.ModelA()
print((type(variable)) is models.ModelA())
print(type(variable) is models.ModelA())
print(isinstance(variable, models.ModelA))
❯ python3 main.py
False
False
True
```

If you put the definition of `ModelA` in the same py file that declares `variable`, i.e., no importing, `print((type(variable)) is models.ModelA())` and `print(type(variable) is models.ModelA())` will be `True`.

However, using `isinstance(variable, models.ModelA)` to check whether a variable is an instance of a class is the preferred way.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. `models.ModelA()` means **an instance of** that class, which is obviously not the type of anything, certainly not the type of another instance. If that's fixed, the results are all `True`. Also, the only difference between your first two `print`s is a redundant extra pair of parentheses. At any rate, importing is not what causes the problem here, and if switching to `isinstance` happened to fix the problem for OP, even though that is the preferred way to do it, that is still only fixing it by accident.

Comment: Whatever went wrong for OP is not reproducible with what is shown; but even supposing that it were, the question is a common duplicate about fundamental technique, with an extremely well-known canonical. Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer what is obviously a duplicate.